# change css using if($'').hasclass()

Tags: jquery

I am showing a notification bar on some pages on my site. 
If the bar is showing I would like to highlight the navigation bar and move it down the page.

The css for the bar is `<div id="infobar_1_1" class="info_bar" style="background-image:... 
<div class="infobar_inner"><span id="infobar_txt" ....</div></div>`

I'm trying to use jquery code 
`if ($('#infobar_1_1').hasClass('.info_bar')) { $(".navbar").css({"background-color":"yellow", "margin-top":"40px"});}`
 but nothing is happening.

```
`$(".navbar").css({"background-color":"yellow", "margin-top":"40px"});`
```

works on every page so maybe there is something wrong with the if() statement.

My site is a wordpress site. 
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
if ($('#infobar_1_1').hasClass('info_bar')) {
```

you dont need to specify the `dot` whenever using [`.hasClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) function

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the `.` for the class name here when using **[.hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/)**:

```
if ($('#infobar_1_1').hasClass('info_bar'))
```

Comment: I removed the . and it still isn't working. should I be using bind() instead?

Comment: Did you receive any error in the console? Seem like the error is coming from the other part of your code.

Comment: there is an console error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input but this error is showing without my code and when I just add `$(".navbar").css({"background-color":"yellow", "margin-top":"40px"});` the error is showing still but the code works so it doesn't seem to be the issue although I'm not sure...

Comment: also the path to the error file is not the path I'm editing so I don't think it is connected at all. (although it is also a jquery file)

Answer (score 2):

The [hasClass()](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) method expects the class name as the parameter, not a class selector so remove the `.` in `.info_bar`

```
$('#infobar_1_1').hasClass('info_bar')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($(".info_bar")){ $(".navbar").css({"margin-top":"35px"});}
```

worked. I'm not sure what was wrong with my original code but it is working now with this code.